Can't install apt package in Docker, while can install in regular shell
I'm trying to install ros-iron-ros2-controller package in my docker image with nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r36.2.0 as base image and installed ROS iron. Unfortunately execution of this line in my Dockerfile fails:
#44 ERROR: process "/bin/bash -c apt install -y ros-iron-ros2-control ros-iron-ros2-controllers ros-iron-controller-manager" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
------
 > [40/44] RUN apt install -y ros-iron-ros2-control ros-iron-ros2-controllers ros-iron-controller-manager:
0.442 
0.442 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
0.442 


4.226 E: Unable to locate package ros-iron-ros2-control
4.226 E: Unable to locate package ros-iron-ros2-controllers
4.226 E: Unable to locate package ros-iron-controller-manager
------


However installation of this package on my laptop (which uses Ubuntu22.04) is going well.
Some information of the image:

Architecture: arm64
OS in container Ubuntu 22.04
There is repository for ROS iron:

#40 [36/44] RUN cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list
#40 0.416 deb [arch=arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy main


Installation of other ROS packages goes well, I've tried ros-iron-std-msgs and it went well
Using rosdep for installation of this package leads to the same problem:

#45 [41/44] RUN apt-get update && apt update && rosdep install -q -y -i --from-path . --rosdistro iron -r --skip-keys="gazebo_ros gazebo_ros2_control"
#45 1.266 Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy InRelease
#45 1.284 Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates InRelease [128 kB]
#45 1.536 Hit:3 https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common r36.2 InRelease
#45 1.702 Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports InRelease
#45 1.808 Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]
#45 2.107 Hit:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease
#45 10.26 Fetched 257 kB in 9s (27.3 kB/s)
#45 10.26 Reading package lists...
#45 13.31 W: https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common/dists/r36.2/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
#45 13.36 
#45 13.36 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
#45 13.36 
#45 14.28 Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy InRelease
#45 14.30 Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates InRelease
#45 14.43 Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports InRelease
#45 14.60 Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security InRelease
#45 14.60 Hit:5 https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common r36.2 InRelease
#45 14.60 Hit:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease
#45 22.92 Reading package lists...
#45 26.16 Building dependency tree...
#45 26.66 Reading state information...
#45 26.71 All packages are up to date.
#45 26.71 W: https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common/dists/r36.2/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
#45 35.47 ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
#45 35.47 to system dependencies:
#45 35.47 tof_driver: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [dt-vl53l0x]
#45 35.47 display_renderers: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [ament_python]
#45 35.47 utils_package: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [ament_python]
#45 35.47 adafruit_drivers: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [smbus2]
#45 35.47 joystick: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [ament_python]
#45 35.47 Continuing to install resolvable dependencies...
#45 48.57 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
#45 48.96 Selecting previously unselected package ros-iron-xacro.
(Reading database ... 125714 files and directories currently installed.)
#45 49.07 Preparing to unpack .../ros-iron-xacro_2.0.9-3jammy.20240419.152244_arm64.deb ...
#45 49.09 Unpacking ros-iron-xacro (2.0.9-3jammy.20240419.152244) ...
#45 49.43 Setting up ros-iron-xacro (2.0.9-3jammy.20240419.152244) ...
#45 58.40 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
#45 58.78 Selecting previously unselected package ros-iron-control-msgs.
(Reading database ... 125754 files and directories currently installed.)
#45 58.88 Preparing to unpack .../ros-iron-control-msgs_5.2.0-1jammy.20240624.133711_arm64.deb ...
#45 58.92 Unpacking ros-iron-control-msgs (5.2.0-1jammy.20240624.133711) ...
#45 59.43 Selecting previously unselected package ros-iron-hardware-interface.
#45 59.45 Preparing to unpack .../ros-iron-hardware-interface_3.26.0-1jammy.20240710.071728_arm64.deb ...
#45 59.47 Unpacking ros-iron-hardware-interface (3.26.0-1jammy.20240710.071728) ...
#45 59.85 Setting up ros-iron-control-msgs (5.2.0-1jammy.20240624.133711) ...
#45 59.91 Setting up ros-iron-hardware-interface (3.26.0-1jammy.20240710.071728) ...
#45 59.95 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.8) ...
#45 64.56 E: Unable to locate package ros-iron-controller-manager
#45 68.56 E: Unable to locate package ros-iron-ros2-control
#45 72.61 E: Unable to locate package ros-iron-ros2-controllers
#45 80.26 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
#45 80.60 Selecting previously unselected package ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport.
(Reading database ... 126443 files and directories currently installed.)
#45 80.69 Preparing to unpack .../ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport_3.1.0-1jammy.20240624.171321_arm64.deb ...
#45 80.72 Unpacking ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport (3.1.0-1jammy.20240624.171321) ...
#45 81.03 Selecting previously unselected package ros-iron-compressed-image-transport.
#45 81.04 Preparing to unpack .../ros-iron-compressed-image-transport_3.1.0-1jammy.20240624.171337_arm64.deb ...
#45 81.06 Unpacking ros-iron-compressed-image-transport (3.1.0-1jammy.20240624.171337) ...
#45 81.42 Selecting previously unselected package ros-iron-theora-image-transport.
#45 81.43 Preparing to unpack .../ros-iron-theora-image-transport_3.1.0-1jammy.20240624.151706_arm64.deb ...
#45 81.47 Unpacking ros-iron-theora-image-transport (3.1.0-1jammy.20240624.151706) ...
#45 81.86 Selecting previously unselected package ros-iron-image-transport-plugins.
#45 81.87 Preparing to unpack .../ros-iron-image-transport-plugins_3.1.0-1jammy.20240624.175154_arm64.deb ...
#45 81.89 Unpacking ros-iron-image-transport-plugins (3.1.0-1jammy.20240624.175154) ...
#45 82.29 Setting up ros-iron-compressed-depth-image-transport (3.1.0-1jammy.20240624.171321) ...
#45 82.36 Setting up ros-iron-theora-image-transport (3.1.0-1jammy.20240624.151706) ...
#45 82.43 Setting up ros-iron-compressed-image-transport (3.1.0-1jammy.20240624.171337) ...
#45 82.49 Setting up ros-iron-image-transport-plugins (3.1.0-1jammy.20240624.175154) ...
#45 82.56 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.8) ...
#45 93.88 ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
#45 93.88   apt: command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-controller-manager] failed
#45 93.88   apt: command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-ros2-control] failed
#45 93.88   apt: command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-ros2-controllers] failed
#45 93.88   apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-iron-controller-manager]
#45 93.88   apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-iron-ros2-control]
#45 93.88   apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-iron-ros2-controllers]
#45 93.88 executing command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-xacro]
#45 93.88 executing command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-hardware-interface]
#45 93.88 executing command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-controller-manager]
#45 93.88 executing command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-ros2-control]
#45 93.88 executing command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-ros2-controllers]
#45 93.88 executing command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-image-transport-plugins]
#45 ERROR: process "/bin/bash -c apt-get update && apt update && rosdep install -q -y -i --from-path . --rosdistro iron -r --skip-keys=\"gazebo_ros gazebo_ros2_control\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [41/44] RUN apt-get update && apt update && rosdep install -q -y -i --from-path . --rosdistro iron -r --skip-keys="gazebo_ros gazebo_ros2_control":
93.88   apt: command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-ros2-controllers] failed
93.88   apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-iron-controller-manager]
93.88   apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-iron-ros2-control]
93.88   apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-iron-ros2-controllers]
93.88 executing command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-xacro]
93.88 executing command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-hardware-interface]
93.88 executing command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-controller-manager]
93.88 executing command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-ros2-control]
93.88 executing command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-ros2-controllers]
93.88 executing command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-iron-image-transport-plugins]
------
Dockerfile:110
--------------------
 108 |     #RUN apt install -y ros-iron-ros2-control ros-iron-ros2-controllers ros-iron-controller-manager
 109 |     
 110 | >>> RUN apt-get update && apt update && rosdep install -q -y -i --from-path . --rosdistro iron -r --skip-keys="gazebo_ros gazebo_ros2_control"
 111 |     
 112 |     WORKDIR /app/.
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -c apt-get update && apt update && rosdep install -q -y -i --from-path . --rosdistro iron -r --skip-keys=\"gazebo_ros gazebo_ros2_control\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1


I've used apt update before installation

So the question is how to fix this problem? Also important to mention that the same Dockerfile was used on Friday (12.07.2024) and everything worked well. The problem occurred only on 13.07.2024
Minimal Dockerfile to reproduce the error:
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r36.2.0
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]


RUN apt update && apt install curl -y
RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg
RUN echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(. /etc/os-release && echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null

RUN apt update

RUN apt install -y ros-iron-ros2-control ros-iron-ros2-controllers ros-iron-controller-manager

To build it I used:
docker build -t test_rosdep --platform linux/arm64 --progress plain .

